# Monotonic decreasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions

I am trying to prove ${{u}}_{n+1}=\frac{3(1+{{u}}_n)}{5+{{u}}_n}$ is decreasing sequence when $u_1 >1$. I can show this by choosing any particular value of $u_1$ but I don't know how to proceed if I want to prove rigorously. Please help me to initiate any idea

Comment: You can post your complete proof here and let us check if it is already enough.

Comment: You want to find a condition on $u_n$ such that $\frac{3(1+u_n)}{5+u_n} < u_n$.  Getting the two intervals on which this inequality holds is an undergraduate algebra task...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, inductively prove that $u_n>1$ for each $n\geq 0$.

Subsequently, prove that $u_{n+1}>u_n$ for each $n\geq 0$ (the quadratic formula may come in handy).

Answer (score 0):

Let, $U_n>1 $for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$2U_n > 2$
$\Rightarrow 3U_n > 2+ U_n \Rightarrow 3(1+ U_n) > 5+ Un$ $ \Rightarrow 3(1+U_n)/(5+ U_n) > 1.$
$U_{n+1} >1$
Hence, Inductively ,we can say, $U_n$ is bounded below by $1$.

Now, let, $U_{n+1} < U_n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$

$\displaystyle U_{n+2}- U_{n+1 }=\frac{(3+3Un+1)(5+Un)-(3+3Un)(5+Un+1)}{(5+In)(5+Un+1)}$

Now, $15+15U_{n+1} +3U_n +3U_{n+1}U_n - 15- 15U_n  - 3U_{n+1} -3U_{n+1}U_n$

$= 12(U_{n+1} - U_n)$

So, $U_{n+2} - U_{n+1 }$

$\displaystyle= 12\frac{U_{n+1} - U_n}{(5+Un)(5+Un+1)}$

Since, $U_{n+1 }< U_n\Rightarrow U_{n+2 }< U_{n+1  }$

By mathematical induction
Hence, $U_n $is monotonically decreasing.
Hence, It is convergent.